# Base64 to File Image Submission Fails in Safari only

Tags: javascript, ajax, file, safari, base64

I have an application that is storing imagines into IndexedDB as Base64 strings.  Then when I go to submit the form the string is interpreted into a file and then sent via AJAX.  This works fine using Firefox but does not work in Safari.  I do not get an error, just a 0 KB file is sent to the folder.

```
getImageFromDB(imageRef,function (imageVal) {                                                                                                                          
    var fileSvc = encodeURI("files/UploadFile")                                                                                                     
    var imgFile = dataURLtoFile(imageVal, imageRef+".jpg");                                                
    urltoFile(imageVal, imageRef+".jpg", 'image/jpg')                                                         
        .then(function(imgFile){
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', imgFile);

            $.ajax({
                url: fileSvc,
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: formData
            });
        })
});


function dataURLtoFile(dataurl, filename) {
    var arr = dataurl.split(','), mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
        bstr = atob(arr[1]), n = bstr.length, u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
    while(n--){
        u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
    }
    return new File([u8arr], filename, {type:mime});
}
```

Why does this work in Firefox but not Safari (both macOS and iOS versions)?

I know I could try to send the data as a BLOB but I was hoping to not have to change the existing web service which is expecting a file.